# How do you use floor/ceil in math, e.g. how does it work exactly?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I read the Wiki, but I am still somewhat confused. Supposedly floor returns the number lowest,  and ceil the number highest. However, I am not sure I understand how this works in freehand form, or how I may implement this myself in a specific thing. Would someone please clarify how ceil and floor works, and how it is used/examples?  Thanks!!

Comment: Here's how to calculate it: $\lfloor 1.1\rfloor = 1$ or $\lfloor -1.2\rfloor = -2$.

Comment: What's a Willie?

Comment: Wiki ... that is what I meant. Cameron, I do not understand

Comment: Is that not rounding to the nearest one?

Comment: Okay well here's what you do. To calculate the floor of a number, you just find the biggest integer that is less than or equal to that number. Like I did above. Can you guess what $\lfloor -3.14\rfloor$ is? No it is not quite rounding to the nearest integer.

Comment: 3.15 is bigger, and 3.13 smaller. Is that correct?

Comment: Those are not integers. The largest integer _smaller_ than $-3.14$ is the integer $-4$.

Comment: Ok ... I get it. What purpose does it serve to map out the nearest integer smaller/bigger though? It still seems to me like rounding off.

Comment: @CameronWilliams could you perhaps give a real-world example?

Comment: I'm not sure what a real world use for it is, in all honesty. It just shows up sometimes in certain contexts, but you're right it is kind of a rounding procedure.

Comment: Well, okay. Thanks for the simple explanation @CameronWilliams !

Comment: @CameronWilliams I have 8 children coming over to paint two easter eggs each. A carton of eggs contains a dozen (12). How many cartons of eggs do I need?

Comment: @rghthndsd Good point! I'm not sure why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put it's two ways of thinking of rounding off a number.
Ceiling rounds up to nearest integer.
Floor rounds down to nearest integer.
If the number is an integer, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to think about floor and ceil from the perspective of the number line.
Let's say you have some decimal number, $2.31$ <sub><sup>(I'm going to be using this number as an example throughout my answer)</sup></sub>
$\hskip2in$[image: numberline]
So, as you can see, the functions just return the nearest integer values.
floor returns the nearest lowest integer and ceil returns the nearest highest integer.

All real numbers are made of a **characteristic** (an integer part) and **mantissa** (a fractional part)
$$\text{Number} = \text{Characteristic} + \text{Mantissa}$$
$$2.31 = 2 + 0.31$$

When floor a number, you can think of it as replacing the Mantissa with $0$
$$\lfloor 2.31 \rfloor = 2 + 0 = 2$$

and ceil can be thought of as replacing the mantissa with $1$.
$$\lceil 2.31 \rceil = 2 + 1 = 3$$

That's not a very popular way of thinking about it but it was 
the way I thought about it when I first started using it in programming.

Remember, the number remains the same when it is an integer.
ie, floor($3$) $=$ ceil($3$) $= 3$

---

Let's now look at the proper definitions along with the graphs for them.

**Floor Function**: Returns the greatest integer that is less than or equal to $x$
$\hskip2in$[image: floor function]

**Ceiling Function**: Returns the least integer that is greater than or equal to $x$
$\hskip2in$[image: ceil function]

Don't let the infinite staircase scare you. It's much more simpler than it seems.
Those "line-segments" that you see are actually called [piecewise-step functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function).

Simply, the black dot represents 'including this number' and the white represents 'excluding this number'.
Meaning  that each segment actually is from x to all numbers less than x+1.

---

Let's look at 2.31 and how it would look on both the graphs at once.
[image: Graph of 2.31 hitting the floor and ceil functions]
You can see that the line $x=2.31$ hits the floor function at the "line-piece" for $2$ 
and hits the ceiling function at $3$

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using the floor function:  I have a number $m$ and I am looking for the smallest number $\ell$ such that $2^\ell\gt m+1$.  To find such a number I would use the expression

$$\ell =[\log_2(m+1)]+1$$

Where the square brackets indicate the use of the floor function.

The `floor` and `ceil` functions in a programming language might use a combination of truncation (rounding towards zero) and comparisons to actually achieve their result.  For example, if `int` is a function that truncates a number to its integer part, then for $x\ge0$ we have `floor(x)=int(x)`, but for $x\lt 0$ it would be

```
y=int(x)
if (y\ne x)
  floor(x)=y-1
else
  floor(x)=y
```